# Watch Julia expressions in Atom/Juno

Tags: debugging, julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

Is it possible to watch Julia expressions in Atom/Juno debugger as it works in other debuggers?

I don't see it

[image]

Did they felt back to Matlab's 30yo approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The closest thing is the workspace pane, which should give you realtime feedback for all defined symbols in the current local or global scope.

Comment: Pity, I was afraid of it :(

Comment: May be a can put obvservable into variable or lambda to simulate watch?